# Replace images with static content wildfly 10

Tags: wildfly, undertow, static-content

In our app the static content on JBoss 7.2 is deployed with a rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite name="rule-1" pattern="^(\/my_app\/(?!(exclude)\/)((.*)\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|PNG|png)))$" substitution="/another.war/my_app/$3" flags="L"/>
```

And it works fine

Now, on wildfly 10 I want to deploy the static content but I can't. The undertow subsystem is:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
                <buffer-cache name="default"/>
                <server name="default-server">
                    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
                    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                        <location name="/my_app" handler="static"/>
                        <filter-ref name="server-header"/>  
                        <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    </host>
                </server>
                <servlet-container name="default">
                    <jsp-config/>
                    <websockets/>
                </servlet-container>
                <handlers>
                    <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
                    <file name="static" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content/my_app" directory-listing="true"/>
                </handlers>
                <filters>
                    <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
                    <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
                </filters>
            </subsystem>
```

The expected results is that the image that want to be showed in the browser is replaced with the image that is on the path, instead is a 404 not found for the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Undertow predicates http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/index.html#predicates-attributes-and-handlers in your virtual host with rewrite tags like this:

Comment: You wrote "like this" and there is nothing :(